# Creating a view similar to androids default 'create/edit contact'

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create  view that is very similar to androids view when creating a contact (in the contacts app), and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how they made it! Is this view using some basic components I perhaps just havn't found yet?

The imagebutton: I can't get the borders to the right size (after a picture is taken, the image will be a different size), and the click animation stops working when the image is changed.

The border between each element: I have done this by simply putting a thin view between the elements, but it doesn't feel like the intended method.

When clicking on for example the text 'Phone', the plus button to the right animates as if it was clicked, how can I achieve this effect?

Finally, the buttons 'Done' and 'Revert' are stuck on the bottom of the screen. What would be the recommended way to accomplish that?

Big thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an open source application. Take a look at the code: [Contacts](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts).

Comment: This was the sort of response i was hoping for! :D

Comment: It's not available anymore, can you please update the link.